# Ignite cursor.getAll() takes very long time to retrieve data

Tags: java, caching, ignite, in-memory-database

I am using Ignite v2 with Java. Below is my ignite node configuration.

```
    CacheConfiguration<Long, MyClass> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<Long, MyClass>();
    cacheCfg.setName("Test_CacheConfig");
    cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
    cacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);
    cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, MyClass.class, Long.class, MyClass.class); 
// Two  fields of long datatype are indexed in pojo MyClass as @QuerySqlField(index=true) 
    cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
```

Using above configuration I am creating `cache` as,

```
    IgniteCache<Long, MyClass> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

I have a large number of records stored in this `cache` **approx. 35 million**.

I am querying this `cache` on two fields. `field1` and `field2` they both are indexed in Myclass. **Ideally, the query returns only one matching record in the cursor.** But when I try the read the record from the cursor using `cusror.getAll().get(0)` it takes around 4-5. This is way too much expensive in my scenario. Below is my query code

```
    SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(
"select *  from MyClass where field1 <= some value and maxIpVal >= some value ");
    //It returns only one record
    QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql);
    System.out.println(cursor.getAll().get(0)); // It takes time to fetch data
```

**Note:**
I am putting records in `cache` using  `CacheStore`. The total number of records are approximately 35 million. I have already configured JVM as recommended here
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need a group index with both fields: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes#section-group-indexes

It is also always a good idea to look at execution plan to check what indexes are used and how the query is executed: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-performance-and-debugging#using-explain-statement

Comment: thanks, I have made indexing and other changes specified in above links and it increased my performance significantly. 
It's now 1 second compared to 3-4 seconds previously. 
However, performance standard we are expecting is 1-10 milliseconds. 
And seems like Apache Redis meets them and I wonder with Ignite it won't be that much fast.

Comment: 1 second sounds too slow, especially if query indeed returns a single entry. Look at the execution plan and check what's going on there. Also don't forget to do warm up - run a query multiple times in a loop before making measurements. JVM JIT compiler needs some time to do all the optimization before you start getting best results.

Comment: Yes exactly, I was about to mention that. After few times warming the JVM I have printed query plan with "Explain" keyword and it only took 0-1 millisecond. However, fetching record from the cursor is still taking 0-150 milliseconds. Considering query returns only one record 150 ms. is also a bit slow.

Comment: Can you create a small project on GitHub that reproduces the issue?